# '[String]' is not convertible to '[NSString]'

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsstring, swift2

I am following the tutorial on this link: http://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift

According to Xcode, there is an error on the line

```
var components = (string as NSString).componentsSeparatedByString(",") as! [NSString]
```

It says that '[String]' is not convertible to '[NSString]'. What is happening exactly, and how should I fix it?

Thanks! Here is the code:

```
import UIKit

func RGB(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
  return RGBA(red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 255)
}

func RGBA(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) -> UIColor {
  return UIColor(red: red/255, green: green/255, blue: blue/255, alpha: alpha/255)
}

extension UIColor {

  class func RGBAColorFromString(string: String?) -> UIColor? {

    if let string = string {

      var components = (string as NSString).componentsSeparatedByString(",") as! [NSString]

      if components.count == 3 {
        components.append("1.0")
      }

      if components.count != 4 {
        return nil
      }

      let red = CGFloat(components[0].floatValue / 255)
      let green = CGFloat(components[1].floatValue / 255)
      let blue = CGFloat(components[2].floatValue / 255)
      let alpha = CGFloat(components[3].floatValue / 255)

      return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: alpha)
    }

    return nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works with this syntax:

```
var components = string.componentsSeparatedByString(",") as [NSString]
```

Comment: I am surprised because his code is working fine for me.

Comment: OP's code is fine in Swift 1.2, the error is for Swift 2 (but indeed OP didn't give this info, I'm going to add the swift2 tag to their question when I can (for now there's a pending suggested edit)).

Comment: `var components: [NSString] = string.componentsSeparatedByString(",")` works as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! What is Apple's reasoning for not allowing 'as!' and use 'as' instead?

Comment: @osibm `as!` or `as?` is used when you don't know whether the conversion (casting) is possible. `as!` will crash at runtime if the conversion is not possible, `as?` would return `nil`. However, `[string]` to `[NSString]` is *always* possible. We know that at compile time, that's why `as` must be used.